# Finding a sublayers position on the screen after several CATransforms?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, quartz-2d

My iPhone app has a mainView. added as a sublayer to this MainView is CircleView. CircleView rotates as the phone turns and tilts as the phone tilts, using 3 concatenated CATransform3D transforms. DotView is added as a sublayer to CircleView. After all these transoforms, I have no easy (or apparent) way of knowing the coordinates of dotView in the mainView coordinate system.

I also have another view, squareView, added to mainview as well. I do know the coordinates of squareView in mainView's coordinate system.

I want to use Quartz 2D to draw a line between a dotView and a squareView. How do I find out out the coordinates of squareView in order to draw a line between the two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the presentationLayer property of the layer in question.